# AJAX append option not valid

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototype, html-select

I try to load the options of a select with an AJAX request. The AJAX request is correct and return what I want. Here is my code :

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {foldertype_id: foldertype},
            onSuccess: function(answer) {
                var folders = JSON.parse(answer.responseText).folders;
                var selectToFill = $('my_select_box');
                for(var i = 0; i <= folders.length; i ++){
                    selectToFill.append('<option id="' + folders[i].value + '" value="' + folders[i].ID + '">' + folders[i].label + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
```

The option are well added nto the select, but they didn't appear in the dropdown. In Chrome I can see there is no color syntax in the option text. See this screenshot to understand well : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oFKf.jpg

As you can see, the grey options are those added by AJAX, and I can't see those one into my select dropdown

Why this is happen ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is using prototype. As I said, the option are well added, just like their are not active

Comment: ahh, didn't noticed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

got an answer here: https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=209624

Typically DOM insertion is using `.insert`

**Example:**

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: {foldertype_id: foldertype},
        onSuccess: function(answer) {
            var folders = JSON.parse(answer.responseText).folders;
            var selectToFill = $('my_select_box');
            for(var i = 0; i <= folders.length; i ++){
                selectToFill[0].insert({after: '<option id="' + folders[i].value + '" value="' + folders[i].ID + '">' + folders[i].label + '</option>'});
            }
        }
 });
```

From the code above, you should be pointing to any last option inside your select element which where you will going to append after, example your index `0` or `1`

**Example Snippet**

```js
const test = ["test1","test2"];

test.forEach(function(index,item){
 const sel = $('my_select');
  sel[0].insert({after: "<option value='"+item+"'>"+item+"</option>"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Prototype/1.7.3/prototype.js"></script>
<select id="my_select" placeholder="test">
<option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After few tries I did make something working. The only issue is that I can't do anything after my insertion. Even a console.log is not working. I explain : I want to create a new Chosen element for the form I've just fill, but nothing I tried works :/

Comment: @Nathan30 sorry but I didn't quite get your issue right now, can you update your post? and be more detailed? thanks! We will try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var htmlToAppend ="";

for(var i = 0; i <= folders.length; i ++){
htmlToAppend += "<option id='" + folders[i].value + "' value='" + folders[i].ID + "'>" + folders[i].label + "</option>";
}
selectToFill.append(htmlToAppend);
```

Comment: I finally try this and this is working : selectToFill.insert(new Element('option', {id: folders[i].value, value: folders[i].ID}).update(folders[i].label));